# How to change the default profile variable in aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, variables, aws-cli

I try to use aws cli with docker images.

the command line like :

```
slu@machine:/c/work/dfsi$ export AWS_PROFILE=role-development
slu@machine:/c/work/dfsi$ aws ecr get-login
```

An error occurred

> (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken
>   operation: User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/slu is not authorized
>   to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *

but I can do:

```
aws ecr get-login --profile=role-development
```

What I want to do isn't obviously write `--profile` and try to do it with hidden `--profile variable`?

How to do that?

Comment: are you asking where the default profile credentials are stored on your computer? Whatever credentials are set within that file under [default] will be used.

Comment: I do not ask default profile, I want to change profile to role-development as default profile, How to do it?

Comment: I think there is another issue here. This seems to be the correct method of switching profiles. Is there anything else about your setup that might be causing this issue?

Comment: when you type 'export' do you see your profile configuration correctly specified? does that name match up exactly with your ~/.aws/config?

Comment: Yes the role-development is defined in ~/.aws/config. I just want to use that profile instead of default profile just like in aws console switch role

Comment: Yes I understand, however you are doing it correctly so if it's not working then there must be something else wrong with your set up which is what I'm trying to help you diagnose.

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I have the exact same issue. Setting AWS_PROFILE and AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE do not help. Only using --profile=xxxxx works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The below environmental variable is working for me as expected.

```
AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=profile-name
```

Answer (score 2):

- step1: `echo $AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` to see what's your environment variable.
- step2: `export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=your_aws_default_profile_name`

To verify, simply run `aws iam list-users` to see what comes back based on your profile.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` set then they will override anything in `AWS_PROFILE` and `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE`